# Firebase crash on App::Create with C++ SDK

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to use Firebase Authentication on Android C++ application. 
When the application executes App::Create, the application crashes and appears these errors:

```
D/dalvikvm( 5562): no method with name='getCodeCacheDir' signature='()Ljava/io/File;' in class Landroid/app/Activity;
W/System.err( 5562): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getCodeCacheDir' signature='()Ljava/io/File;' in class Landroid/app/Activity;
W/System.err( 5562):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/Log'
D/dalvikvm( 5562): open_cached_dex_file : /data/data/com.outpause/cache/app_resources_lib.jar /data/data/com.outpause/cache/app_resources_lib.dex
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/Log'
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback'
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback'
E/dalvikvm( 5562): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult', referenced from method com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback.initializeWithPendingResultOrTask
W/dalvikvm( 5562): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 3 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult;) in Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback;
D/dalvikvm( 5562): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm( 5562): Failed resolving Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback$PendingResultCallback; interface 5 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/ResultCallback;'
W/dalvikvm( 5562): Link of class 'Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback$PendingResultCallback;' failed
D/dalvikvm( 5562): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0009 at 0x08 in Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback;.initializeWithPendingResultOrTask
I/dalvikvm( 5562): Failed resolving Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback$TaskCallback; interface 8 'Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener;'
W/dalvikvm( 5562): Link of class 'Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback$TaskCallback;' failed
D/dalvikvm( 5562): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x000c at 0x12 in Lcom/google/firebase/app/internal/cpp/JniResultCallback;.initializeWithPendingResultOrTask
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp'
W/dalvikvm( 5562): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp'
E/firebase( 5562):  local_class
```

What is happen?